# Stub protected List in base class for unit-test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I want to test if a method adds an object to a list in the base class.

My problem is that the list is protected so I can´t populate it in my test arrangement. Therefore the list is empty and my method fails to add the object at a specific index.

How do I make a stub list and use it instead of the real base class list without making it public?

I'm using NUnit and Moq.

Here´s some code to imitate my problem:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    readonly List<PhoneNumber> _numbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();

    public void AddNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber)
    {
        _numbers.Add(phoneNumber);
    }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    protected List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public void AddNumberToPersons(int index, PhoneNumber phoneNumber)
    {
        Persons[index].AddNumber(phoneNumber); // <-- Need to test if 
                                               // this gets called without errors
    }
}

[Test]
public void AddNumberToPersons_WhenAddingNumberToPersons_NumberGetsAddedToList()
{
    // I think I need to use a stub list or else the list is empty 
    // and index is out of range.

    // Assert that number is added to the list.
}
```

Comment: Is it really matters whether phone number was added to person or not? How this will affect behavior of your class? Persons are protected, so you really don't care on it's state. You should care on changes which will affect users of your class

Comment: Hm, your right, its not a matter whether phone number was added or not.
What i need to test is when i call AddNumberToPersons(int index, PhoneNumber phoneNumber).
Persons[index].AddNumber(phoneNumber); gets executed.
But i still need a stub list to execute that line without throwing a exception right?

Comment: How does executing `AddNumber` method will affect behavior of your class? It will behave differently after adding phone number to one of persons?

Comment: No it don´t, so i won´t need a test for AddNumberToPersons?
What if i refactored something in AddNumberToPersons that brakes the call to 
AddNumber, don´t i want a test that tells me i broke AddNumberToPersons?

Comment: I'm not sure you want to mock or stub the properties of the class you are testing. If there is a getter or a method that returns the list of phone numbers, build your Assert using the output and comparing it with what you inserted. Usually you want to use test doubles for dependencies that are complicated or connected, where using the real thing in your unit test would be cumbersome.

Comment: So in my arrange i call a method to fill the list with one person so i won´t get a out of range.
Act by calling AddNumberToPersons.
And assert by calling a method that gets the list for me and compare it´s content.
Don´t i test 3 methods in one test then?
Do you have any recomendations on how to make a test double for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

There's some good discussion in the comments about why you might want to think about what it is you're trying to test.  That said, there may be situations where you do want to setup your class for testing using its base class.  Rather than using Moq in this situation I would tend to use a hand rolled testable version of the class.  So, in your test project if you can create a testable version of `DerivedClass` like this:

```
public class TestableDerived : DerivedClass {
    public TestableDerived(List<Person> people) {
        this.Persons = people;
    }
    public List<Person> AccessablePersons { get { return this.Persons; } }
}
```

The `TestableDerived` class has access to the `protected` members of the hierarchy, so you can populate it during the arrange portion of your test.  Normally you could then validate that the state of the appropriate `Person` has been updated to add the number.  This might give you a test something like this:

```
var sut = new TestableDerived(new List<Person>(){new Person(), new Person()});

sut.AddNumberToPersons(1, new PhoneNumber { Number = 1234 });

Assert.AreEqual(1, sut.AccessablePersons[1].Numbers.Where(x=>x.Number == 1234).Count());
```

In your particular example, this wouldn't work however because your `Person` class has no way to access PhoneNumbers once they have been added.  There are ways that you could get around this, however this doesn't seem to be the focus of your question so I've chosen to believe this is an omission from your example code and added a `Numbers` accessor.